# Avoiding SCSS rule repetition

Tags: sass, rule, repeat

I have a file with defined a couple of *CSS3* rules for border shadow, gradients and etc..
For comparability I need to add the `behavior: url('/assets/css3pie.htc');` for support in IE.

```
@mixin box-shadow($props) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: #{$props};
     -moz-box-shadow: #{$props};
          box-shadow: #{$props};
  behavior: url('/assets/css3pie.htc');
}
```

The behavior rule is added for most of my *CSS3* like *border-shadow, gradients and border-radius*.

Unfortunately I noticed that in the output when I use two or more of those CSS3 rules I also end up with **more than one** of the `behavior: url('/assets/css3pie.htc');` rules for the given object.

An example output is:

```
button {
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  behavior: url("/assets/css3pie.htc"); # first time defined by the border-radius rule
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  behavior: url("/assets/css3pie.htc"); # second time, defined from the box-shadow rule
}
```

Which is the best solution? Is there a way to check the inheritance tree and whether a rule is already defined?

Comment: This arguably seems to be a bug in SCSS; there is no valid reason to include duplicate properties in the generated output, so this should be addressed in SCSS itself, you shouldn't be required to work around this issue. I would advise you to post a bug report for SCSS.

Comment: Actually, @lanzz, this is not a bug and there's a discussion about it https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/309

Comment: @electric_g The issue you've referred to seems about repeated _properties_; I'm talking about repeated _full rules_, i.e. same property _with the same value_.

Comment: @lanzz So there isn't another solution except doing it manually (like the answer below) or waiting for a fix?

Comment: I still think you should report a bug to the SCSS developers; if they resolve this issue, you won't need a solution anymore.

Comment: I've created an issue located here: https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/555

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks that it'a a *SCSS* bug.

Most of the properties will get overwritten in similar case, but there are some properties that can be defined more than one time like `background`.

That's why it's not an *SCSS* default behavior of overwriting rules. The reason why the `behavior` property isn't defined like a `should be overwritten` property is a bug.

The prettiest way to solve the issue is by removing the `behavior` definition property and defining a `css3pie` mixin, like that:

```
@mixin css3pie() {
  behavior: url('/assets/css3pie.htc');
}
```

Then to use it, add the following line to every *CSS3* enabled element:

```
.css3-enabled-element {
  @include css3pie;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug since it is desired behavior. I'll up vote though since more separation results in better code and well it fixes your problem. It is desired behavior because without doing it this way you could never override any properties.

Answer (score 3):

While working on a similar case, I came up with this solution.

Due to:

> IE interprets the URL for the behavior property relative to the source
>   HTML document, rather than relative to the CSS file like every other
>   CSS property

([more info](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#relative-paths)), the url is kept in a variable, to be easily changed according to the project:

```
$pie-path: "/myproject/PIE.htc";
```

No prefix needed unless 2.1 Android and below and 3.2 iOS and below or CSS3PIE for IE8 and below so this mixin is not really needed anymore – [more info](http://generatedcontent.org/post/37949105556/updateyourcss3)

```
@mixin border-radius ($val) {
    @each $prefix in '' {
        #{$prefix}border-radius: $val;
    }
    @extend %pie !optional;
}
```

No prefix needed unless 3 Android and below and 4.3 iOS and below or CSS3PIE for IE8 and below – [more info](http://generatedcontent.org/post/37949105556/updateyourcss3)

```
@mixin box-shadow ($val...) {
    @each $prefix in -webkit-, '' {
        #{$prefix}box-shadow: $val;
    }
    @extend %pie !optional;
}
```

A note about "`!optional`": this flag is to avoid SASS to throw an error if that @extend doesn't work (e.g.: the placeholder is in the .scss file for IE and not in the general one, but the mixin is called by both) – [more info](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#the__flag)

Placeholder selector: at the beginning of the file to allow following rules to override any position/fix property.
A note about "`position:relative`": it's declared here to fix the z-index issues (disappearing backgrounds/borders/shadows) – [more info](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#z-index).
Depending on the css and project, this rule can break the layout

```
%pie {
    behavior: url($pie-path);
    position: relative;
}
```

Usage

```
.item1 {
    @include border-radius(10px);
}
.item2 {
    @include border-radius(5px);
    @include box-shadow(10px 10px 10px rgba(#000, .3));
}
.item3 {
    @include box-shadow(10px 10px 10px rgba(#F90, .8));
}
```

Output

```
.item1,
.item2,
.item3 {
    behavior: url("/myproject/PIE.htc");
    position: relative;
}

.item1 {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.item2 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.item3 {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.8);
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.8);
}
```

The behaviour rule is not repeated and the css is more clean, with the properties declared only once, thereby facilitating the separation of styles between IE and non-IE.

Answer (score 1):

Pass another argument and use the `@for` directive to specify if the mixin ought to output the extra code:

```
@mixin box-shadow($props, $css3pie: true) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: #{$props};
     -moz-box-shadow: #{$props};
          box-shadow: #{$props};
  @if $css3pie {
  behavior: url('/assets/css3pie.htc');
  }
}

@include box-shadow(2px 2px 2px black) // Include behavior
@include box-shadow(2px 2px 2px black, false) // Don't include behavior
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a SASS library called [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) instead of 
writing these types of mixins.

This library already has a comprehensive list of css3 mixins, and also has css3pie support if you so need it.

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work by serving the correct `content-type` to the web browser. 
In other words, I added the following line to my apache `.htaccess` file :

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
```